# How does web browser run ".jsx" file during development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jsx, vite

I'm new to react ".jsx" files, I can now run the `dev` and `build` test.

I have a question about how browser runs ".js" files. If the project is `build`, then the browser is running ".js" file, which I understand because browser can run ".js" file.

but during `dev`, when I check the app source in browser's dev mode, it shows that in the html file, there is a ".jsx" file!

[image]

So how is it possible? can a browser run ".jsx" file? or during dev mode, the dev server (like npm or vite) is doing something secret? the browser shows source code as ".jsx" but actually it's running other files (hidden by npm or vite)?

Comment: Browsers don't actually care about file extensions in most cases; what matters is the MIME type that the server provides, and the local server could certainly do on-the-fly compilation to JavaScript and return an appropriate MIME type for that. That said, I'm betting that the server *doesn't* do that, and that the magic here actually comes from the `<script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>` near the top.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not run `JSX` directly and it's not even supported by browsers. JSX is a **syntax extension** used for javascript within HTML, for readable and understandable code. You can even write pure JS inside your react project and it will still run.

`JSX` is not natively understood by browsers. Instead, it needs to be converted into valid JavaScript using tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/). This process is known as [transpilation](https://daily.dev/blog/transpilers-how-they-work), which ensures that browsers can properly interpret and run the JSX code embedded within React applications.

You can see that when you actually `build` your application, you don't get any JSX in the build/dist folder. Its just JS and CSS.

Answer (score -2):

JSX is not native JavaScript. Browsers are built to interpret and execute standard JavaScript code. JSX, with its HTML-like syntax embedded within JavaScript, is not something a browser understands by default.
Due to syntax differences JSX uses elements that look like HTML tags, but they are actually JavaScript expressions that create React components. Browsers don't have the built-in mechanisms to parse and render these custom elements.